# How to read a MutableList<String> to Parcelable?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I have a class `User` that implements the `Parcelable` interface. `User` also has a property of type `MutableList<String>`. I would like to know how to read/write this type for `Parcelable`.

Here's my code so far

```
data class User(
    val contactNumber: String,
    val email: String,
    val fullName: String,
    var instanceToken: String,
    val isAdmin: Boolean,
    val isValid: Boolean,
    val organization: String,
    val registrationTokens: MutableList<String>,
    val uid: String,
    val unitNumber: String
) : Parcelable {

    constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
        source.readString() ?: "",
        source.readString() ?: "",
        source.readString() ?: "",
        source.readString() ?: "",
        source.readBoolean(),
        source.readBoolean(),
            source.readString() ?: "",
            source.readStringList(),
            source.readString() ?: "",
        source.readString() ?: ""
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.let {
            it.writeString(contactNumber)
            it.writeString(email)
            it.writeString(fullName)
            it.writeString(instanceToken)
            it.writeBoolean(isAdmin)
            it.writeBoolean(isValid)
            it.writeString(organization)
            it.writeStringList(registrationTokens)
            it.writeString(uid)
            it.writeString(unitNumber)
        }

    }
```

For the write part, there's a `writeStringList()` method which is convenient. But for the read part, the provided `readStringList()` does not actually return `MutableList<String>`. It only returns `Unit` / `void`. Hence, it spits out a compilation error.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: You could consider `@Parcelize` and don't implement the `Parcelable` interface yourself.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-studio-tips-for-productivity-1-6015fc469a6d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`createStringArrayList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createStringArrayList()). `readStringList` is intended to reuse a single `List` instead of creating a new one each time, this isn't what you want here.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. I'll have to cast it like so: `source.createStringArrayList() as MutableList<String>`. Is that correct? 

Also, is my usage of `writeStringList()` above correct?

Comment: There should be no need to cast anything; it returns an `ArrayList<String>` which is a subtype of `MutableList<String>`. `writeStringList` should be correct, yes. (And look into `@Parcelize` as the comments mentioned.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was doubtful of using Parcelize when I started the project since some developers reported unexpected behavior with it sometimes as it's still an experimental feature. I didn't want to take the risk facing difficulties down the road so I manually implemented `Parcelable`. Once it is not experimental anymore, I'll for sure implement it in my project. It's nice not having to worry about modifying the `Parcel` methods everytime  I need to add or remove a property.